# PHPMailer HTML e-mail gets quoted

Tags: phpmailer

I'm sending HTML mails through PHPMailer to my Gmail account (Inbox app), but I cannot build a body which wouldn't get quoted
(you get new e-mail and all there is is "..." which you click and rest of the mail shows, it's for hiding previous conversation if you Reply).

I have tried including  tags, but as soon as I add `<br>` or `<p>`, it all gets quoted.

Best I could make work was

```
$message = "<html><body><p>Lalalala</p> trololo </body></html>"
```

which resulted in Lalalaa "...", if I add paragraph around trololo, all I get is "..."

Anybody came accross this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very deterministic experience (one mails sent 2x got quoted differently each time), the thing that helped was wrapping the entire mail in `<span>` tags.